# html css toolbar

Tags: html, css

im having problem adjusting the width of the toolbar, when I increase the 100px it all goes wrong, also how can I round the margin corners?

heres a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bArx5/

thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it all goes wrong'? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: people on SO really hate **"it all goes wrong"** questions, you need to define exactly what is wrong...

Comment: well try changing the width from 100 to eg 200 and you will see, I gave a demo as its hard to explain.

Comment: @ppaul Tried changing from 100px to 200px width.  Everything looks exactly as expected and nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you increase the width of each `a` element it will wrap the list (if that is what you mean with "it all goes wrong"). You can prevent this by setting a minimum width of your `ul` element ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HYhBe/)):

```css
ul#list-nav {
    margin: 20px;
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

This has to be adjusted according to the width of your `a` elements.

I don't really know what you mean by "how can I round the margin corners", but if what you want is a rounding of your anchor elements, you can add a border radius to them:

```css
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}​
```